# sentence begins with "only to"

Tags: word-meaning

> Their rejection of what he stands for was fully exhibited on Sunday
>   when Trump joined world leaders in Paris to mark the centennial of the
>   end of the World War I, **only to** hear French President Emmanuel Macron
>   who said under the Arc de Triomphe that “nationalism is a betrayal of
>   patriotism.”

What does "only to" mean here? Or what did the author want to express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**only to do sth**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/only-to-do-sth) : used to show that something is surprising or unexpected:
>
> *He spent months negotiating for a pay increase, **only to** resign from his job soon after he'd received it.*

In this context: Trump went to Paris to join the other leaders in marking an important anniversary, but *may have been surprised* when Macron made a speech directly criticizing Trump's earlier statement that he (Trump) thinks of himself as a "nationalist".  The speech suggests France (and possibly the other European leaders) categorically reject Trump and his policies, even as Trump tried to demonstrate solidarity with them.

Comment: Thanks.
PS:Your given example sentence confused me for a while. I understand the meaning after reading the Chinese version of cambridge dictionary. "received it" means "pay increasement", I had thought it was "the job".

Comment: @zhang  I agree the pronoun is a bit ambiguous.